# Unity URP point light мигает/не работает

Tags: unity3d

Делал игру в Unity с URP, и столкнулся с проблемой что некоторые источники света мигают или не работают вообще. Вот видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CYQ_81pdl-g . Я гуглил решение этой проблемы, и там писали что проблема заключается в том что в юнити есть лимит на рендеринг света, например на сцене 16 источников света а лимит 8, то он и зарендерит только 8. Без URP можно повысить лимит до 16 через меню Quality, но в URP такого нет. Версия юнити 2022.3.8f1. Также находил решения для URP, но там либо версия просто старая, либо это вообще был LWRP. Буду рад если кто то поможет с этим. (запечь свет нельзя ибо уровень генерируется процедурной генерацией)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Зайди в файл Renderer своего URP ассета и измени настройку Rendering Path на "Forward+". Все равно будут некоторые ограничения на количество источников освещения на камеру, но зарендерить получится уже гораздо больше восьми источников.